# SQL Server Cluster Failover Making DB Inconsistency Error

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I encountered the following DB tables inconsistency error whenever I do a cluster 'move' over from **Server-A** to **Server-B** and then do a DBCC CHECKDB on the database in Server-B:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error:incorrect
>   checksum. It occurs during read of page(1:142) in dtabase ID 4 at
>   offset 0x0000000011c))) in file
>   'X:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDB.mdf.

Sometimes, the above DB error may vary and occurred to other DB tables :(

The two servers (A & B) are using Window Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition (SP1). Each server has its own NAS (SUN Storage 7410), and using Double-Take Availability to create a single copy of the database across the servers. Also, each server has 2 iSCSI connectors (redundancy purpose) connected to the NAS.

The peculiar thing is the DB inconsistency error did NOT happen when I change either one of the following configuration:

1. Move from **Server-B** to **Server-A** (no DB error on Server-A using DBCC)
2. Software disable one of the 2 iSCSI connectors on Server-B
3. Use internal local harddisk, instead of NAS in Server-B (Server-A still using NAS)

Anyone can help to advise me what else can I do to diagnose the problem to Server-B.

Answer (score 1):

After many trials and errors, the fault lies in NIC card of Server-B. After I replaced it, the cluster move-over operates smoothly without any DB inconsistency ;) However, I do not understand how a NIC card can cause DB inconsistency (a 'ping' to the NIC card works well)

Comment: Given that the NIC card is the way the server talks to the storage, if the card isn't doing things correctly it'll read the data incorrectly from the NAS and you'll get errors.